# Visual Studio: Setup Project - !Condition

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, installation

In a visual studio setup project, how do I get the inverse of a condition? Specifically, I am looking to run a script if a file does not exist (ie the Exists condition is false).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check for 'False' on your property, so instead of the condition being 'MYPROPERTY', make it 'MYPROPERTY = False'.  (And yes, in spite of your better instincts, use a single '=' not '==')